# DbUnit-query returning data of type BigInteger

Tags: dbunit

I am new to DbUnit and am facing the below issue while running my integration test.

I am using in memory h2 database and have created the tables as per my requirement.

While running a specific query which returns me count of customer Ids , I get a class cast exception as the resultset returned by running with DbUnit (for this "count") is of type BigInteger whereas my data bean property as well as the test table column type is "int".

Please let me know why I am getting this BigInteger type in result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The returned column is an expression, i.e. count(x), not the column itself (x).  Sometimes, the result of a function on a column can result in type promotion.  From http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/guide.html under "Integral Types":

> There is no built-in limit on the size of intermediate integral values in expressions. As a result, you should check for the type of the ResultSet column and choose an appropriate getXXXX() method to retrieve it. Alternatively, you can use the getObject() method, then cast the result to java.lang.Number and use the intValue() or longValue() methods on the result.

Comment: Thanks ... it was helpful...earlier i thought its dbunit but then realized it was h2 db which was the root cause.